# Finding Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

This was an exam question and I was absolutely lost.

Find positive constants $a,b$ such that the function

$$
\frac{1}{z^2+a} + \frac{1}{z+b}
$$

has three Laurent series, one for each of the domains $|z|<1, \,\, 1<|z|<4, \,\, |z|>4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $a=1$ and $b=4$ or $a=16$ and $b=1$.